# Error on Integral Mathematica 12

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I can't solve this with Mathematica:

```
y[x_] := 1/(Sqrt[F+(A^2/4+B) x^2] + (A/2) x);
Integrate[y[x],x]
```

`A` and `B` are positive but `F` could be negative or positive.

Please help me.

Also I found the problem is integral:

```
y[x_] := (Sqrt[F + (A^2/4 + B) x^2])/Bx^2 + F;
Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

Comment: The command to take the anylytic integral is `Integrate`  not Integral. Further you have to give assumptions for the parameters to help MMA `Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, 6}, Assumptions -> {A > 0, B > 0, F > 0}]`  or `Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, 6}, Assumptions -> {A > 0, B > 0, F < 0}]`

Comment: I used your code but it's not working.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The revised (first) code seems to be working (in V12.3.1).

Comment: Try `Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, 6}, GenerateConditions -> False]`. But note that `Bx` is a single parameter, and `B x` is the parameter `B` times the variable `x`; so add a space.  Add parentheses as necessary, too, to get your intended integrand.

Comment: Michael E2 you are right B x is different it was my bad. :)